# @SpringBootTest autowire repository cannot save data to real database

Tags: unit-testing, spring-data-jpa, repository, in-memory-database, spring-boot-test

I try to make a unit test with real database (mean not in-memory database).
 this is my config file:

```
@TestConfiguration
@EnableJpaAuditing
public class TestConfig {

  @Bean
  @Primary
  public DataSource getDataSource() {
    HikariDataSource hikariDataSource = new HikariDataSource();
    hikariDataSource.setJdbcUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/faptv");
    hikariDataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
    hikariDataSource.setUsername("mansion");
    hikariDataSource.setPassword("mansion");
    return hikariDataSource;
  }
}
```

This is my sample test:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.NONE)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {TestConfig.class})
@DirtiesContext
@Transactional
public class BaseEntityTest {
  @Autowired
  private TBL120Dao dao;

  @Test
  @Sql("classpath:/sql/abc.sql")
  public void test() {
    TBL120Dto dto = new TBL120Dto();
    dto.setUserId("xxx");
    dto.setUsername("ccsc");
    dto.setPasswordHash("passss");
    dao.save(dto);
    assertThat(dao.findByUserId("kkk").isPresent()).isTrue();
  }
}
```

This is my /sql/abc.sql

```
insert into tbl120(user_id, password_hash, username) value ("kkk", "ssss", "Ssss");
```

When the test is finished:
I see in my real database: it's has new row from sql.
But it don't have the row with userId 'xxx' from the test method. And, when I debug inside test method, It only exist once record of userId 'xxx' when I try to execute dao.findAll() (note that in real database not exist this, real database only exits data from sql), it can not access real database.

how can I save and select data from real database?

Answer (score 0):

Spring transactional tests rollback automatically by default. See [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.2.2.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/testing.html#testcontext-tx-enabling-transactions) for how to customize this.